# Chef certification check fail "cookbook upload" despite success "knife ssl check"

Tags: chef, self-signed-certificate, cookbook

I had placed crt key from "Distributor", and then checked and successed.
But "knife cookbook upload" failed.

- Chef Server

  - Hostname : "Distributor"
  - Cent OS 7
  - chef-server-core-12.4.1-1.el7.x86_64
- Workstation(kitchen)

  - Hostname : "Workstation"
  - Cent OS 7
  - chefdk-0.11.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Why certification failed, and what is workaround?

---

```
[account@Workstation chef-repo]$ knife ssl check
Connecting to host Distributor:443
Successfully verified certificates from `Distributor'
[account@Workstation chef-repo]$ knife cookbook list

[account@Workstation chef-repo]$ knife cookbook upload example
Uploading example      [1.0.0]
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: distributor - hostname "distributor" does not match the server certificate
ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://distributor/bookshelf/organization-ccad6652ef52c0e8dee7dd227773ea8a/checksum-92a639ad39af9c4f51d46b7bfcf69bb6?AWSAccessKeyId=52bdfe8139b3bdfb710a544169b3682c11c9e174&Expires=1458289269&Signature=N8Pih1UY1rt1vGTVvlLoZFG0oMQ%3D, retry 1/5
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: distributor - hostname "distributor" does not match the server certificate
ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://distributor/bookshelf/organization-ccad6652ef52c0e8dee7dd227773ea8a/checksum-2379ce6d82f773a3ce050c87b32c4c7d?AWSAccessKeyId=52bdfe8139b3bdfb710a544169b3682c11c9e174&Expires=1458289269&Signature=2wMxcjUAEd7lMNQ/RwZv30/ssbk%3D, retry 1/5
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: distributor - hostname "distributor" does not match the server certificate
ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://distributor/bookshelf/organization-ccad6652ef52c0e8dee7dd227773ea8a/checksum-2645d8b91137912a590407fa530be964?AWSAccessKeyId=52bdfe8139b3bdfb710a544169b3682c11c9e174&Expires=1458289269&Signature=F6uDdJFzlAgV9vBlK92Sf7RLWck%3D, retry 1/5
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: distributor - hostname "distributor" does not match the server certificate
ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://distributor/bookshelf/organization-ccad6652ef52c0e8dee7dd227773ea8a/checksum-f7e821e5c5e80279c1cb09315ca6e43a?AWSAccessKeyId=52bdfe8139b3bdfb710a544169b3682c11c9e174&Expires=1458289269&Signature=1NUEjokCCmhZ%2BRA/RUxWHGx8QvM%3D, retry 1/5
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you got the wrong .pem file selected in your `knife.rb`
check your `knife.rb` and check if your key is correct. it should look something like this (inside your `knife.rb`)

```
client_key               "#{current_dir}/yourkey.pem"
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem was fixed by installing a newer Chef Server Core.

Comment: honestly, no idea what your answer/comment means.